# chrome.management.onInstalled event not fired

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have nothing in my background.js except

```
var extensionID;
chrome.management.onInstalled.addListener(function(info) {
    console.log('somethingz installed...');
});
```

I also have "management" permission declared in manifest.json.
However, the onInstalled Event is not fired and console never output the sentence...
chrome.runtime.onInstalled does work, but I need to listen to uninstalled event to do some cleaning work in my code. Chrome.runtime seems does not support uninstalled event.

Could someone tell me what's the problem is? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Installed or **un**installed? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to catch your own uninstall?

Comment: Hi Xan. Both onInstalled and onUninstalled events are not fired...

Comment: If you're trying to catch them for your own extension, no, they will not be fired. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes... Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chrome.management` API is for managing *other* extensions.

You can catch your own install/update with [`chrome.runtime.onInstalled`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled).

By design, you *cannot* anyhow detect your extension being disabled or uninstalled. At most, you can use [`chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-setUninstallURL) to report uninstallation to some web service and clean-up server-side data.

Note that uninstalling the extension will wipe local/sync storage associated with it.